# Microsoft Excel 2012 add a date when I open the document

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was wondering if it was possible to add a date every time I open my excel sheet.
I know the function is `=TODAY()`, how can I proceed to do this for example let's say :

```
       A
1 02/05/2013 (Today's date, it would be automatically written unless it is today's date)
2 03/05/2013 (Tomorrow's date, if I open it tomorrow.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a Macro . The Workbook_Activate is fired at the load event so this should work:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("A1").Value) Then
         Range("A1").Value = Date
    End If         
End Sub
```

If that doesn't work, change the sub to

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
```

**edit**

I updated my code based upon your comment, but this may be a design fault. If you're always writing to A1 for example, it means by the next day there will be a value. I think you need to test the value, however, this is possibly over kill for such a simple command.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    If Not Range("A1").Value = Date Then
         Range("A1").Value = Date
    End If         
End Sub
```

If it were me, I'd just overwrite the value every time you load and not bother with the check since it's not expensive.

Comment: Tank you very much, I'll google how to check if a cell is empty so I can set A1 to A2 if A1 != empty